# unexplained variations in postgresql insert performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, caching, sql-insert

I have a processing pipeline generates two streams of data, then joins the two streams of data to produce a third stream. Each stream of data is a timeseries over 1 year of 30 minute intervals (so 17520 rows). Both the generated streams and the joined stream are written into a single table keyed by a unique stream id and the timestamp of each point in the timeseries.

In abstract terms, the c and g series are generated by plpgsql functions which insert into the timeseries table from data stored elsewhere in the database (e.g. with a select) and then return the unique identifiers of the newly created series. The n series is generated with a join between the timeseries identified by c_id and g_id by the calculate_n() function which returns the id of the new n series.

To illustrate with some pseudo code:

```
-- generation transaction
begin;
c_id = select generate_c(p_c);
g_id = select generate_g(p_g);
end transaction;
-- calculation transaction
begin;
n_id = select calculate_n(c_id, g_id);
end transaction;
```

I observe that generate_c() and generate_g() typically run in a lot less than a second however the first time calculate_n() runs, it typically takes 1 minute.

However if I run calculate_n() a second time with exactly the same parameters as the first run, it runs in less than a second. (calculate_n() generates a completely new series each time it runs - it is not reading or re-writing any data calculated by the first execution)

If I stop the database server, restart it, then run calculate_n() on c_id and g_id calculated previously, the execution of calculate_n() also takes less than a second.

This is very confusing to me. I could understand the second run of calculate_n() is taking only a second if, somehow, the first run had warmed a cache but if that is so, then why does the third run (after a server restart) still run quickly when any such cache would have been cleared?

It appears to me that perhaps some kind of write cache, generated by the first generation transaction, is (unexpectedly) impeding the first execution of calculate_n() but once calculate_n() completes, that cache is purged so that it doesn't get in the way of subsequent executions of calculate_n() when they occur. I have had a look at the activity of the shared buffer cache via pg_buffercache but didn't see any strong evidence that this was happening although there were certainly evidence of cache activity across executions of calculate_n().

I may be completely off-base about this being the result of an interaction with a write-cache that was populated by the first transaction, but I am struggling to understand why the performance of calculate_n() is so poor immediately after the first transaction completes but not at other times, such as immediately after the first attempt or after the database server is restarted.

I am using postgres 11.6.

What explains this behaviour?

**update:**

So further on this. Running the `vacuum analyze` between the two generate steps and the calculate step did improve the performance of the calculate step, but if I found that if I repeated the steps again, I needed to run `vacuum analyze` in between the generate steps and the calculate step every time I executed the sequence which doesn't seem like a particularly practical thing to do (since you can't call `vacuum analyze` in a function or a procedure). I understand the need to run `vacuum analyze` at least once with a reasonable number of rows in the table. But do I really need to do it every time I insert 34000 more rows?

Comment: After bulk loading (a lot of) data into a table, you need to run `vacuum analyze` on that table to update the statistics, otherwise the query optimizer will not have enough information to come up with a good execution plan.

Comment: Not only that, but there are also hint bits that the first reader sets. That may account for the slowdown. A `VACUUM` will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks people. The `vacuum analyze` did do the trick. I assume I should not be planning to execute this every time I do an insert, but only after I have some data in the tables. Would that be correct?

Comment: "then why does the third run (after a server restart) still run quickly when any such cache would have been cleared?"  PostgreSQL depends heavily on the file system cache provided by the OS.  That cache would not be cleared merely by restarting PostgreSQL.  I don't think this is the explanation for your overall question, just clearing up a possible misconception.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes I did experiment with flushing the caches using an echo of 3 into /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches but this didn't consistently eliminate the speedup.

Comment: OK, that is the correct way to do it.  First restart, then drop_caches.  (The other way around and anything PostgreSQL writes out while it is restarting will repopulate the OS cache after it was flushed.)